# Is it possible to restrict SQL server access to a Hamachi VPN?

Tags: sql-server, vpn

We already use Hamachi to link our isolated servers together, but it is possible to restrict access to certain applications so that they can only be seen on the server or via Hamachi's VPN.

From our logs we can see "far eastern" probing of our SQL Server installations, and ideally we would like to restrict access to SQL Server boxes. We have a unsophisticated network topology of leased servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is running on a recent Windows Server version (preferably 2008 R2), then just use the windows firewall to deny access to your SQL ports except from the hamachi VPN IP addresses you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is why SQL Server's should never be exposed to the public Internet.  Instead the SQL Server should be configured with private IPs which are not NAT'ed to a public IP.

Configure your routers or firewall and configure them to now allow any access from the outside world.

Comment: Thanks - It is an inherited system - which we are trying to modernise

Comment: Sounds like there is probably a decent amount of stuff to fix.